# rightAnchor constraint did not apply when added programmatically - swift

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, ios-autolayout

When I Added rightAnchor constraint, constant= 20 did not apply. In leftAnchor is ok

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    addSubview(collectionView)
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([collectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 20),
                                 collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor),
                                 collectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: 20),
                                 collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor)])
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: You probably want `leadingAnchor` and `trailingAnchod` rather than left/right as these will respect right-to-left locales automatically

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a really strong feeling that this is what you wanted to do there for `rightAnchor`.

`collectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -20)`

If you want padding from the right or bottom you should use negative values.

---

**Rule of thumb:** Whatever is left or upwards of something is negative.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding 20+rightAnchor of your superview. It should be -20

```
addSubview(collectionView)
collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([collectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 20),
                             collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor),
                             collectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -20),
                             collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor)])
```