# UITableViewCell's content view height is not adjusting for the dynamic font (NSLayoutConstraints)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

I am having difficulties adjusting table view cells to automatically resize for dynamic type fonts. Note that I am using layout constraints in code, not in storyboard.

Here is my table view setup code:

```
tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)
tableView.register(ChatAnalyticsCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: ChatAnalyticsCell.reuseIdentifier)
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

Here are my 2 labels and image view setup in `ChatAnalyticsCell` class

```
private var iconImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero,
                                              size: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)))
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0.25, green: 0.3, blue: 0.72, alpha: 1)
    return imageView
}()

private var segmentLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.textColor = UIColor.gray
    label.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .footnote)
    label.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true

    return label
}()

private var segmentDataLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.13, green: 0.15, blue: 0.19, alpha: 0.9)
    label.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
    label.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
    return label
}()
```

Here is the function where I add subviews and setup constraints, to resize properly for the dynamic-type font.

```
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    setupSubviews()
}


private func setupSubviews() {
    addSubview(iconImageView)
    iconImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 15.0).isActive = true
    iconImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    iconImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20.0).isActive = true
    iconImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20.0).isActive = true

    // Analytics segment label
    addSubview(segmentLabel)
    segmentLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iconImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    segmentLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    segmentLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true

    // Segment data label
    addSubview(segmentDataLabel)
    segmentDataLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: segmentLabel.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    segmentDataLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: segmentLabel.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    segmentDataLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: segmentLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
    segmentDataLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true

    contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 80).isActive = true
}
```

Note that when I run the code, there are no constraints breaking, but the layout is not properly updated. Please see the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add all the views to the `contentView`!

```
contentView.addSubview(yourView)
```

One more thing - you might want to change[(why?)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51395076/7734643) this constraint,

```
segmentDataLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
```

to,

```
segmentDataLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
```

The rest of the constraints look ok to calculate the height of the `contentView`.

Comment: Omg, thank you so much, I've banged my head against the wall the whole morning. It was that problem, adding subviews to content view instead of just view. Thank you so much!!!!!!!

Comment: @Miki been there when i was new to autolayout. Even the constraint issue. I know the feeling! :'D